# How could I detect if particular Activity is displayed currently?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-activity

I have standard `ListView` activity linked to the database:

```
dbHelper = new DbAdapter(this);
dbHelper.open();
recordsCursor = dbHelper.fetchAllRecords();
startManagingCursor(recordsCursor);

String[] from = new String[]{DbAdapter.KEY_1, DbAdapter.KEY_2};
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.background};

adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, recordsCursor, from, to);
```

User has an option to update the list manually thru the menu item. It runs the task to get updated date from the server:

```
new SyncTask(getApplicationContext(), true).execute();
```

(second parameter indicates if this is manually started synchronization or automatic)

Once synchronization finished (`onPostExecute`), I would like to update the list (`fetchAllRecords`, `changeCursor` etc.) if the same activity is still displayed. How could I understand if this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike [fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) you don't have any methods to check the activity lifecycle, but it's simple to add something similar:

```
private boolean mResumed;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    mResumed = true;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mResumed = false;
}

private void isResumed() {
    return mResumed;
}
```

Simply call isResumed() when your background task completes to see if the Activity is still visible on the screen.

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't it be `false` at `onPause`? The main question - what if user just chosen the menu item to refresh the list and then waits for its completion? `onPause` and `onResume` will not be called in such case, so `mResumed` will be undefined...

Comment: If you have an activity active/visible on your device, the onResume has always been called. I've corrected the mistake in the example that you pointed out too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i don't understand in deep the main problem.

You say before:

" what if user just chosen a item in menu item to refresh the list and then waits for its completion? "

If this happens you can update the listview at the end of the task like you say before "onPostExecute" (Without a problem).

But in the other case you can retrive the state of the activity with methods that return flags i you want or if your using fragments you can getActivity() to do something. Ever when the Activity will be displayed the activity do a 'Resumen' step so like Philio explains before.

Conclusion, you can update the listview automatic in onResumen and you can update it manually in onPostExecute in the syncTask. This method will be called in automatic or manual mode doesn't matter.